# Exception handling with Kotlin with Spring

Tags: spring, kotlin

Roman Elizov [has a great blog post on how to use exceptions with Kotlin](https://elizarov.medium.com/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07). He emphasizes that catching exceptions in kotlin is usually code smell.

But does that mean that I should be able to throw exceptions freely in my Spring application if I am using application level exception handlers?

More specifically let's say I have function that looks up an item in the database, and a controller that calls this service. If the item is not in the database, should I return a nullable from the service or should I throw an exception? (The controller doesn't have to try/catch the exception because all applications are handled at framework level)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case and context. But generally I would say that you should throw an exception annotated with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`.